# PHP gives date error for some (but not all) site visitors

Tags: php, datetime, date, timezone

I'm writing a script that uses the date() function for logging purposes.

In various places I use `date('Y-m-d')`, `date('Y-m-d H-i-s')`, and `date(DATE_RFC822)`.

When I access the page from my computer, using Safari, Firefox, and Chrome in Mac OS 10.6, the page loads as expected and doesn't result in an error.

When a colleague (who is in the same general geographic area and same timezone as me) accesses the page from her computer, using the same OS and browsers as myself, she receives the following error in **all** browsers:

`date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead`

I have assumed that the **date()** function is agnostic to the client's timezone, but this seems to suggest otherwise.

I resolved the problem by specifying the timezone via `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");`
, but I would like to understand why the client should have any bearing on the server's timezone.

How and why does the client's timezone affect PHP's treatment of timezones, particularly with regard to the **date()** function?

PHP Version: 5.2.5

More info from phpinfo():

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2007.9
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    US/Eastern`
```

Comment: user time zone is irrelevant, php is server side, its shows your server date.

Comment: @Dagon I understand that its purpose is to show the server's date/time. But how would you explain the fact that a call to the date() function throws an error on one machine but not on another machine?

Comment: are you using `ini_set('display_errors',VAL)` anywhere in your code? Perhaps  conditional upon user agent?

Comment: my explanation would be that you are misinterpreting the situation, php is server side and has no idea what a browser is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for the feedback.

I determined it's actually due to the fact that the webserver is distributed across two server nodes. One node is running PHP 5.2.5 and another node is running 5.1.6. I was served by the PHP 5.2.5 node every time I accessed the page, and the other person was being served by the node with the older version of PHP.  So even though we were accessing the exact same URL, we were in effect being served by different webservers. Very bad situation.

The solution of course is to make the nodes identical to one another. As you all said, there's no way the client could affect the date() function.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. You might have an error in your code in some user agent dependent area, but there's nothing about a users browser, OS, or Computer that would affect the code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's errors/notices are echoed out as soon as they are triggered (unless you are using outputbuffering), so it's ***possible*** that your browsers found the error/notice outside the `<html>` tag, and so discarded it, whereas your friend's browsers perhaps re-incorporated it back into the DOM~~